# Weird crash issue on iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios4, crash

Since iOS 4.3 SDK is not in beta anymore, i believe i can talk about it here.

I'm using `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` flag in my application to relaunch the application everytime (instead of resuming).
 
Now, it was working perfectly before, but now, my application is crashes on random (startup/resume) instances, and i don't get anything out of the crash logs. I don't have any theories at this point. Anyone?

**Debug Console:**

```
/SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer/ProtocolBuffer-51.2/Runtime/PBRequester.m:684 server returned error: 503
```

**Console:**

```
Mar 14 12:06:21 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[444] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Mar 14 12:06:21 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[444] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/FCE3BCD3-EA2F-4E60-9C37-08189F19AA67 [69] (sandbox)
Mar 14 12:06:24 unknown MobileStorageMounter[443] <Notice>: (0x3ea6148c) idle_timer_callback: Exiting after idle timeout
Mar 14 12:06:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[445] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Mar 14 12:06:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[445] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/FCE3BCD3-EA2F-4E60-9C37-08189F19AA67 [69] (sandbox)
Mar 14 12:06:37 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[447] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Mar 14 12:06:37 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[447] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/FCE3BCD3-EA2F-4E60-9C37-08189F19AA67 [69] (sandbox)
Mar 14 12:06:39 unknown UIKitApplication:com.MyiPhone.MyApp[0xa818][447] <Notice>: /SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer/ProtocolBuffer-51.2/Runtime/PBRequester.m:684 server returned error: 503
Mar 14 12:06:39 unknown ReportCrash[448] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyApp[447]
Mar 14 12:06:39 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Warning>: Application 'MyApp' exited abnormally with signal 10: Bus error: 10
Mar 14 12:06:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.MyiPhone.MyApp[0xa818]) Job appears to have crashed: Bus error: 10
Mar 14 12:06:39 unknown ReportCrash[448] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MyApp_2011-03-14-120639_MyiPhones-iPhone.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

**Crash log:**

```
Incident Identifier: ABE26317-A6E2-434B-9B0D-3364AA02A5A9
CrashReporter Key:   591c589277b1722c020483cfc7438c08b7e30aad
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         MyApp [423]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/FCE3BCD3-EA2F-4E60-9C37-08189F19AA67/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]
 
Date/Time:       2011-03-14 11:52:40.143 +0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3 (8F190)
Report Version:  104
 
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000008
Crashed Thread:  0
 
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib               0x3597ec98 0x3597c000 + 11416
1   ProtocolBuffer                0x32a26fb8 0x32a24000 + 12216
2   ProtocolBuffer                0x32a26cea 0x32a24000 + 11498
3   ProtocolBuffer                0x32a280f0 0x32a24000 + 16624
4   Foundation                    0x31162230 0x31151000 + 70192
5   Foundation                    0x31162138 0x31151000 + 69944
6   CFNetwork                     0x30ddb576 0x30dcd000 + 58742
7   CFNetwork                     0x30dd0fb2 0x30dcd000 + 16306
8   CFNetwork                     0x30dd10ca 0x30dcd000 + 16586
9   CFNetwork                     0x30dd0e34 0x30dcd000 + 15924
10  CFNetwork                     0x30dd0de6 0x30dcd000 + 15846
11  CFNetwork                     0x30dd0d58 0x30dcd000 + 15704
12  CFNetwork                     0x30dd0cd6 0x30dcd000 + 15574
13  CoreFoundation                0x34982a72 0x3490d000 + 481906
14  CoreFoundation                0x34984758 0x3490d000 + 489304
15  CoreFoundation                0x349854e4 0x3490d000 + 492772
16  CoreFoundation                0x34915ebc 0x3490d000 + 36540
17  CoreFoundation                0x34915dc4 0x3490d000 + 36292
18  GraphicsServices              0x31db5418 0x31db1000 + 17432
19  GraphicsServices              0x31db54c4 0x31db1000 + 17604
20  UIKit                         0x350ccd62 0x3509e000 + 191842
21  UIKit                         0x350ca800 0x3509e000 + 182272
22  MyApp                 0x0000b7b8 0x1000 + 42936
23  MyApp                 0x000021d4 0x1000 + 4564
 
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x30c783ec 0x30c66000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a276d8 0x349f3000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a27bbc 0x349f3000 + 215996
 
Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x30c78fbc 0x30c66000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x30b39094 0x30b33000 + 24724
2   libdispatch.dylib             0x30b3a04a 0x30b33000 + 28746
3   libdispatch.dylib             0x30b3960a 0x30b33000 + 26122
4   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a2758a 0x349f3000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a27bbc 0x349f3000 + 215996
 
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x30c783ec 0x30c66000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a276d8 0x349f3000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a27bbc 0x349f3000 + 215996
 
Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x30c75c00 0x30c66000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x30c75758 0x30c66000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                0x349832b8 0x3490d000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                0x34985562 0x3490d000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                0x34915ebc 0x3490d000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                0x34915dc4 0x3490d000 + 36292
6   WebCore                       0x3658d37a 0x36587000 + 25466
7   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a2630a 0x349f3000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a27bb4 0x349f3000 + 215988
 
Thread 5:
0   CoreFoundation                0x349c0470 0x3490d000 + 734320
1   CoreFoundation                0x34916f98 0x3490d000 + 40856
2   CFNetwork                     0x30e4ad3a 0x30dcd000 + 515386
3   CFNetwork                     0x30e4b594 0x30dcd000 + 517524
4   CFNetwork                     0x30e4b738 0x30dcd000 + 517944
5   CFNetwork                     0x30e1c7dc 0x30dcd000 + 325596
6   CFNetwork                     0x30e4f152 0x30dcd000 + 532818
7   CFNetwork                     0x30e4f4da 0x30dcd000 + 533722
8   CFNetwork                     0x30de0ec0 0x30dcd000 + 81600
9   CFNetwork                     0x30e4ebe6 0x30dcd000 + 531430
10  CFNetwork                     0x30e4ed40 0x30dcd000 + 531776
11  CoreFoundation                0x3492aa1a 0x3490d000 + 121370
12  CoreFoundation                0x3492a9b6 0x3490d000 + 121270
13  CoreFoundation                0x3492a8aa 0x3490d000 + 121002
14  CoreFoundation                0x3492a75c 0x3490d000 + 120668
15  CFNetwork                     0x30e51c14 0x30dcd000 + 543764
16  CFNetwork                     0x30ddf3f4 0x30dcd000 + 74740
17  CFNetwork                     0x30ddf376 0x30dcd000 + 74614
18  CoreFoundation                0x3498748a 0x3490d000 + 500874
19  CoreFoundation                0x349884a2 0x3490d000 + 504994
20  CoreFoundation                0x34982a72 0x3490d000 + 481906
21  CoreFoundation                0x34984758 0x3490d000 + 489304
22  CoreFoundation                0x349854e4 0x3490d000 + 492772
23  CoreFoundation                0x34915ebc 0x3490d000 + 36540
24  CoreFoundation                0x34915dc4 0x3490d000 + 36292
25  Foundation                    0x3117b7f6 0x31151000 + 174070
26  Foundation                    0x3116e382 0x31151000 + 119682
27  Foundation                    0x311e05c6 0x31151000 + 587206
28  libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a2630a 0x349f3000 + 209674
29  libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a27bb4 0x349f3000 + 215988
 
Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x30c75c2c 0x30c66000 + 64556
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x30c75f92 0x30c66000 + 65426
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a245f4 0x349f3000 + 202228
3   CoreFoundation                0x349273f0 0x3490d000 + 107504
4   CoreFoundation                0x34988c0e 0x3490d000 + 506894
5   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a2630a 0x349f3000 + 209674
6   libsystem_c.dylib             0x34a27bb4 0x349f3000 + 215988
 
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x0014fda0    r1: 0x346ab94e      r2: 0x001b80c0      r3: 0x00000008
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x353acad0      r6: 0x0013f6c0      r7: 0x2fdfe904
    r8: 0x000001f7    r9: 0x3e97b72c     r10: 0x3ea5c024     r11: 0x001b689c
    ip: 0x3e97b084    sp: 0x2fdfe8ec      lr: 0x32a26fbf      pc: 0x3597ec98
  cpsr: 0x000f0030
 
Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x20fff +MyApp armv7  <031d167d8e8234d2a824cdbe2f6299df> /var/mobile/Applications/FCE3BCD3-EA2F-4E60-9C37-08189F19AA67/MyApp.app/MyApp
   0xc5000 -    0xc9fff  AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7  <977d3eb9b0a4389e85e0e8eb64806759> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <8dbdf7bab30e355b81e7b2e333d5459b> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30536000 - 0x3054ffff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3067e000 - 0x3072dfff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30730000 - 0x30740fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30741000 - 0x3088dfff  MediaToolbox armv7  <46c1dd5571de3f7dae97dcde85ca933c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x30915000 - 0x3092afff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x309f2000 - 0x30a39fff  CoreLocation armv7  <565c18af7dfc3c92a63cc4c249913650> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x30a3a000 - 0x30a3dfff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <0479a171c00d3f629d639713acb72b5b> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x30a49000 - 0x30a4bfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <de8392b1117135e592a16e1cb6d26af5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30a82000 - 0x30a85fff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x30b33000 - 0x30b40fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <6c4eeb08757b365f8429ef6747f89ad3> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x30c66000 - 0x30c7dfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <29eb602b615b3c3b95722868100a2d1c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x30ca9000 - 0x30d4ffff  Celestial armv7  <1d37083fe4253a2fb271c0ca0a42e283> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x30dc0000 - 0x30dc7fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x30dcd000 - 0x30e8cfff  CFNetwork armv7  <84a2d312145e3dbf97aea052927dcdb9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x30e8d000 - 0x30e8dfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x30eaf000 - 0x30eb1fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x30ebe000 - 0x30f53fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x30f68000 - 0x30f6dfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x30fa4000 - 0x30fa7fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x30fe3000 - 0x31000fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3100e000 - 0x3100ffff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x31014000 - 0x31026fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <6d30b5ef735f36a79cfc82c9b6606db9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x31027000 - 0x3105ffff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31070000 - 0x310dffff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x31151000 - 0x31270fff  Foundation armv7  <60d1a3b3937c3c7ab21d701fb337346c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31288000 - 0x313a9fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <54e27b8aa66c32b48ffeadadcc514331> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x313aa000 - 0x314b2fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x31689000 - 0x316c9fff  CoreMedia armv7  <66ee3ed5265f3d49a274dc9a07d27d52> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x316ce000 - 0x316d3fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <1eaf25ddd98e3a249bca536671c5819d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x316d4000 - 0x31703fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3172b000 - 0x31730fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x31768000 - 0x31768fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31769000 - 0x31789fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x317d1000 - 0x317dcfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x318f0000 - 0x318fcfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c78c28a259ad35ddb01512beb5fcea95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x318fd000 - 0x31904fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x31960000 - 0x319adfff  CoreMotion armv7  <e0349aa7dd1c3454a970ea1939279801> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x319b6000 - 0x31cc9fff  GeoServices armv7  <8bbb5da6471a3e0d83a55a32c4d1fa9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x31cd9000 - 0x31d82fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x31db1000 - 0x31dbdfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c37066a0784335d189f009ff4965717d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x31ec6000 - 0x31f14fff  GMM armv7  <03cb1e098c4932e58b0933dfc58f9116> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x31f79000 - 0x31fa2fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x31fbc000 - 0x31fc1fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x32326000 - 0x32326fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x32355000 - 0x3238dfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x323b6000 - 0x323b6fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x323b7000 - 0x323cafff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x32440000 - 0x3247ffff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <b5735b0f3dba32c087c5b58aa48ae592> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x32480000 - 0x32496fff  EAP8021X armv7  <b755ecad7b6a3009a5f4a0fdc5f9bdd7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x324ed000 - 0x324f1fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <2e841b3daf303b38bbd82e0954659af4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x324f6000 - 0x325a7fff  WebKit armv7  <8f2fd63295d83121b1db9097938ad31f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x325a8000 - 0x325ddfff  AddressBook armv7  <64500984cfb13a098c3c687c37a80fff> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x326ff000 - 0x32701fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x32760000 - 0x32767fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x32768000 - 0x3279bfff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x32801000 - 0x3284bfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x32852000 - 0x32889fff  Security armv7  <163414ba17df347ca76088015010e2c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x328d7000 - 0x328ddfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3293f000 - 0x32949fff  ExternalAccessory armv7  <eebb4bdbbefb37419b884ffa011e1dc5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework/ExternalAccessory
0x32953000 - 0x3298ffff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <79d00adb09de3da991ed21f48f27adb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x32990000 - 0x329eefff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d3f7360687333cad987890c314ae0d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x329ef000 - 0x32a23fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <aec2e22a2055380e82d4d0279faad0a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32a24000 - 0x32a2afff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <c9798b4dd29335248000d698dea938bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3460d000 - 0x346c9fff  MapKit armv7  <56b5ea34e6753b6f810f34f0a71d84f9> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x346ca000 - 0x346dcfff  VoiceServices armv7  <d219dd8a59c93390b3461a015e28b29c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x346e1000 - 0x346eafff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x346eb000 - 0x346edfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x346ee000 - 0x3470dfff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34787000 - 0x348a1fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34908000 - 0x3490cfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <36e96d0a7dda330281a43172d0ada49a> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3490d000 - 0x349f2fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <4f643539f91f330790f112ea7150b3a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x349f3000 - 0x34a74fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <caa1846ad2583d1b84c1a15c50c126a2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x34a77000 - 0x34a81fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34ae9000 - 0x34b1cfff  StoreServices armv7  <a74659288dea34bca7a7911c19cf2c28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x34b66000 - 0x34b74fff  OpenGLES armv7  <f02d1c50f0f33991adb1a2caed02eb77> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x34b75000 - 0x34b7bfff  IAP armv7  <c0f4c99a1b493e489948f231ad9238e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x34c0a000 - 0x34c5bfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x34c62000 - 0x34c67fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <a19b1caf96c73568b14a1660f147ae2f> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x34c68000 - 0x34d55fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x34d8e000 - 0x34d8ffff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x34d90000 - 0x34d99fff  ITSync armv7  <dc57c003aad83864827ccf95fc579563> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x34e3a000 - 0x34e3bfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x34e3e000 - 0x34e41fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x34e42000 - 0x34e4ffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3509a000 - 0x3509bfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <5f077c4d204d3cd7b04452c42d41f763> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3509c000 - 0x3509dfff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3509e000 - 0x3542bfff  UIKit armv7  <bc8d14fa59e136b6a28ac025384daf08> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3553b000 - 0x3553ffff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <2c61a8f7e7bf32d890e957d768d769ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x35646000 - 0x356e3fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x356fb000 - 0x357fffff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <f63386018d703534b766514e4bbbd1d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x3590a000 - 0x3590cfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <4d521bd4a1be3448a7d2bac1d09c5ff9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x3590d000 - 0x3594ffff  CoreAudio armv7  <d45e275525ef3c32b36e0f1020cad705> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3597c000 - 0x35a40fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <f855251d90a53bdbb5d5a39fdbde6d9b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x35c96000 - 0x35cdcfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <2b9ebb05fdea38938dde802c8280b3ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x35d24000 - 0x35d2cfff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <d0167be199b234f5bd233380111b2735> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x35ddf000 - 0x360c6fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <652c97e211553d4e84968a61f62a0ac5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x360c7000 - 0x36104fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3620a000 - 0x3625ffff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x36260000 - 0x36260fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <68322643de8030978c862de530055bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x36261000 - 0x3626afff  MobileWiFi armv7  <5b634ed28af339719e3c279224531ccb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x36273000 - 0x362b6fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <ffab9d7f5b5b315085783caf030932bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x363dc000 - 0x363ddfff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x36587000 - 0x36b8ffff  WebCore armv7  <9c7e4a156f6a381ea02f99ece48a46fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36b90000 - 0x36ce4fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <3b599e96ffe93b1ea2aa6026dee809dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
```

Please advise.

**Update:**
The problem magically disappears if i try to use my application using GPRS instead of WiFi.

Comment: I experience this issue early on launch of the application on the device when I build with optimizations on (the LLVM 2 compiler). If I turn optimizations off it does not occur.

Comment: Thanks Jim, after a day spent looking for answers, you helped me fix it. Switched back to LLVM+GCC and all is smooth again :)

Comment: Also see [iOS Debugging Magic [Technical Note TN2239](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html) and [Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports (Technical Note TN2151)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If was used MKReverseGeocoder then be sure that you did not release reverse geocoder at `-reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError:`
If the problem is this then try to replace `[reverseGeocoder release];` to `[reverseGeocoder autorelease];`

Comment: thats just awesome! how did you find out?

Answer (score 2):

> This problem is something that has been introduced in the Golden
>   Master since the seeded betas did not have it, and it comes down to
>   the (in my case) reverse geocoder.
>
> Google is sending you a 503 error code (this is pretty standard and it
>   happens when google thinks that you are abusing their service). Since
>   the geocoder is successfull most of the times, the crash seems random,
>   but it isn't. If you want to replicate it, have a proxy (like Charles
>   proxy) returning you 503 and you will see the crash coming every time.
>   Try also disabling location services on your device and you will see
>   that you do not have this problem anymore.
>
> -- Another forum

That's exactly what's happening. I was connected to WiFi when i was experiencing this issue, and when i turned WiFi off, the application didn't crash anymore. It was using GPRS to retrieve the location information, now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution is to set the delegate to nil before you release the geocoder. So you should add

```
[reverseGeocoder setDelegate:nil]; 
[reverseGeocoder release];
```

Answer (score 0):

H,
There is enough information for the `Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)`

Would suggest you to go thought the below link...

http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2009/07/20/iphone-sigbus-issue/

Comment: I'm familiar with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but this case is unique. Why? Because i'm not getting any log! You can see in the crash log that even the system APIs are not symbolized. And, the problem magically disappears if i try to use my application using GPRS instead of WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't allow a single device to retrieve its location more than once within 60 sec, hence working with another method (http request instead, JSON needed) when (MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError.

It works for me on 4.3.3 (3GS) and tested for 30-40 times retrieving user's location consecutively without a crash, hope it helps!

```
- (void) retrieveCurrentLoc {
self.geoCoder =
[[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate] autorelease];
    geoCoder.delegate = self;

    [geoCoder start];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

NSString *fetchURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?    q=%@,%@&amp;output=json&amp;sensor=true", [NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%f",mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude], [NSString      stringWithFormat:@"%f",mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fetchURL];
    NSString *htmlData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *json = [parser objectWithString:htmlData error:nil];
NSArray *placemark = [json objectForKey:@"Placemark"];
if ([[[[[placemark objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"AddressDetails"]objectForKey:@"Country"]objectForKey:@"Thoroughfare"]objectForKey:@"ThoroughfareName"] != NULL){
    currentAddress = [[[[[placemark objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"AddressDetails"]objectForKey:@"Country"]objectForKey:@"Thoroughfare"]objectForKey:@"ThoroughfareName"];}
else {
    currentAddress = [[placemark objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"address"];
    }
}
```