# how error is solved:-/SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer_Sim/ProtocolBuffer-51.2/Runtime/PBRequester.m:684 server returned error: 503 using reverseGeocoding?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, reverse-geocoding

When i am using reverse geocoding in iphone i get this error in console.

> /SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer_Sim/ProtocolBuffer-51.2/Runtime/PBRequester.m:684 server returned error: 503

What does it mean and how this error can be removed to get the geocoding information of current location? I have run this in both simulator and device and same error occurs from last two days. Few days back it gives the proper information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird crash issue on iOS 4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295841/weird-crash-issue-on-ios-4-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve this problem in following ways:
First in my interface,i use

```
MKReverseGeocoder *mkReverseGeocoder;
```

and in my implementation

```
CLLocation *currLocation;
    currLocation = [locationManager location];

    if(mkReverseGeocoder)
    {
        [mkReverseGeocoder autorelease];
    }

    mkReverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:[currLocation coordinate]];

    [mkReverseGeocoder setDelegate:self];
    [mkReverseGeocoder start];
```

and use the delegate method

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Details:" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    [msg release];
}
```

After doing this I can get reverseGeocoding information.